# C++ Delimiter for newline and again for :

Tags: c++

Say I have a textfile "Employees.txt" with Employee name and ID.

Like so:

```
John:d4250
Sarah:s5355
Alan:r4350
```

If I have a very very basic Employee class which has a constructor for Name and ID
and I wish to read from this textfile and insert them into a vector

Am I best to use something like:

```
void GenericProgram::loadEmployees()
{
 string line;

 ifstream empFile("employees.txt");
 if(empFile.fail())
   {
    cout << "input file opening failed\n" << endl;
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

     while (!empFile.eof())
     {
        string empName;
        string empID;

        while (getline(empFile, line, '\n'))
        {
            // this will give me the line on its own

            // now how to delimit again using ':'

            // then do something like
            Employee e(empName, empID)
            employeeVector.push_back(e);


        }
        empFile.close();
    }

}
```

I apologise that this is so basic. Brain is failing on me. I was wondering if there are better ways to read from files to populate objects with streams.

Comment: Never write `while (!f.eof())`, see http://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/981959,  `while(getline(...))` already handles the EOF case

Comment: Also "this has been answered but I didn't understand it" is a poor reason to  ask the same thing again. Try harder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add to your code

```
int pos = line.find(":", 0);
if (pos != std::string::npos)
{
   std::string empName(line.begin(), line.begin() + pos);
   std::string empID(line.begin() + pos + 2, line.end());
}
```

For multiple ":"

```
std::vector<std::string> str;
std::vector<size_t> positions;
positions.push_back(0);
do
{
   positions.push_back(line.find(":", positions.size() - 1));
}
while(positions[positions.size() - 1] != std::string::npos);
for (int i = 0; i < positions.size(); i+=2)
{
   str.push_back((line.begin() + positions[i], line.begin() + positions[i+1]));
}
```

But i haven`t tested it.

Comment: I get this error from 'line' on the third line with empID:

std::string line

Error: no instance of constructor "std::basic_string<_Elem, _Traits, _Alloc>::basic_string[with _Elem=char, _Traits=std::char_traits<char>,_Alloc=std::allocator<char>]" matches the argument list 

argument types are: (std::_String_iterator<std::_String_val<std::_Simple_types<char>>>, const size_t)

I assume you meant to insert this inside :
while (getline(empFile, line, '\n'))

Comment: Oh my bad. Sorry.

std::string empID(line.begin() + pos + 2, line.end());

Comment: Thanks a lot :) What should I search for to read up about this method?

Comment: @user3665874 careful, unless you're assume you're always parsing direct data directly (eg. what about a line with no ':') this will fail.

Comment: And what happens if there is no `':'` in the line?  As a general rule, either use the standard functions of `<algorithm>` (whose `std::find` will return the end iterator if it doesn't find the character), or use `std::string::substr()` (which accepts length of `std::string::npos`) with the results of the member functions of `std::string`.  (Although in this case, I suspect that some wort of error handling would be appropriate, maybe doing nothing but outputting an error message if there is no `':'`.)

Comment: If there are no ":" in line. The function return std::string::npos. It`s equivalent to size of your array. You need to use something like this:

if (pos != std::string::npos)
{
   //good
}
else
{
   //there are no : in your line
}

Comment: Does anyone know what to search for to read up about this? I want to do the same thing for when there are more than one ":" in the line.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. You can do it by using only std::string. Or using CString. Or you can use stl algorithms. I saw in your code std::string and suggested this method.
You need to know find method in std::string. I read about methods in http://www.cplusplus.com.
For example std::string::find is here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/find/

Comment: Alright thanks a lot, will do :) 

With a file with multiple ":" when I use this "line.begin() + pos + 1, line.end()" on my second string I start at the correct position but then I get the entire remaining line (I assume because of line.end()). Do I need to use find(":") to stop at the next ":" then?

Comment: It`s will be better to find all positions first. std::vector<size_t> positions;
int pos = 0;
while(pos != std::string::npos)
{
   pos = line.find(":", pos);
   positions.push_back(pos);
}
and then create an array of strings